# How to use Image.file widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
'''
I/flutter ( 7954): The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 7954): Cannot open file, path = 'image.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
I/flutter ( 7954): 
I/flutter ( 7954): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 7954): #0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:366:9)
I/flutter ( 7954): (elided 13 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 7954): ...
I/flutter ( 7954): 
I/flutter ( 7954): Path: image.png
I/flutter ( 7954): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image]

I am using image.file to display the widget but it throws the below exception how to solve that and I add my code as image.what is the major difference between image.asset widget and image.file widget.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the correct location of the file:

```
File file = new File('directoryLocation/image.png');
```

Another way to load images, is to add them to the `assets` folder in the project, then in the `pubspec.yaml`, you can do the following:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

Then do:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image(image: AssetImage('assets/my_icon.png'));
}
```

Check the docs:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: In image.file I give the directory location of the file but it throws the exception like this        Cannot open file, path = '/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download//_image.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: from where are you getting the file? If you are getting the file from the gallery in the device, then just use the image_picker plugin https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: I am getting the file from downloads folder.

Comment: if it's an image then use the plugin i linked above

Comment: Okay I try that plugin

Answer (score 0):

`Image.asset` is used to load images from your projects `assets` folder. As because its already available in the project and pretty straight foreword to use.

```
Image.asset('assets/image.jpg');
```

On the other hand `Image.file` is used to load images from devices internal/external storage. This way you have to locate the image using ImagePicker or any other library to get the `path` of the image. Using this `path` create a File object and provide it to `Image.file`.

```
String path = 'your/image/path/here';
File imageFile = File(path);
Widget image = Image.file(imageFile);
```